# Adding life cycle to Time Profile instrument

Tags: xcode, instruments

I'm trying to debug my app launch time using time profiler instrument.

But i know i'm suppose to have a life cycle graph under the CPU Usage, but i don't have it.

[image]

How can i add it to there?

Thanks

Comment: i restarted Xcode and it came back.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, and unfortunately, the answer seems to be that you only see the life cycle graph if your device/iOS version is new enough. I wondered about this for a whole day and then switched to an iPhone 5 that was on iOS 10 and these sections magically came back. It didn't show up on my iPod even after full updating it so if you have a newer phone or are capable of upgrading that seems like the only way to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a couple combinations of iOS devices and Xcode / Instruments versions. The life cycle section appeared using iOS 11 and Xcode 9 beta, but when I tried an older iOS 9 device using Xcode 8 and 7 it wasn't there.

[image: Life Cycle view]

What combination of device OS and Xcode / Instruments are you seeing this on?

Comment: I met, No lifecycle until iOS updated to the latest.